# Sort custom array according to a string array in SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have a Custom Array like this:

```
 var myStudentArray1: Array<Student!> = []

     myStudentArray1.append(Student(sCategory: "A+", sName: "Zara"))
     myStudentArray1.append(Student(sCategory: "B-", sName: "Koli"))
     myStudentArray1.append(Student(sCategory: "AA", sName: "Asim"))
```

I have another String array with same one element of that array1 but in different sequence, like this:

```
let myStudentArray2: Array<String!> = ["Asim", "Zara", "Koli"]
```

**How do I sort myStudentArray1 based on myStudentArray2 ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to iterate through the second array, and for each entry there find corresponding entry in myStudentArray1, and add them to a third array. That will contain items sorted in the order of the second array myStudentArray2

```
func sortStudents(students: [Student], byNames: [String] ) -> [Student
{

  var result = [Student]()

  for name in byNames {
     let students = students.filter{ $0.sName == name}
     if students.count > 0{
        result.append(students[0])
     }
  }
  return result

}
```

Now you can call this function to get the sorted results as:

```
let sortedResults = sortStudents(myStudentArray1, myStudentArray2)
```

Comment: Getting a consecutive line error here **if let students = students.filter{ $0.sName == name}{ **

Comment: @AsimKrishnaDas oh, I had just typed it, now fixed. Pl. check

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to just sort them both based on the same thing.

```
myStudentArray1.sortInPlace{$0.sName < $1.sName}
myStudentArray2.sortInPlace{$0 < $1}

for i in 0..<myStudentArray1.count {
    print("\(myStudentArray1[i].sName) = \(myStudentArray2[i])")
}
// Output: Asim = Asim | Koli = Koli | Zara = Zara
```